# primefaces with flex

Tags: apache-flex, jsf-2, primefaces

how can I open a screen in flex, swf, by a menu primefaces? I tried to open a file inside with pure html and it worked, but failed to open within a file tagged < ui:composition>

Comment: What do you mean `open a screen in flex`? Please add more details, what is the epected output? Can you place some code which works (pure html) and code which deoesn't work (facelets) ?

Comment: I dont think Flex and PF will mix easily. You could design your Flex app to take a parameter and open appropriate screen there. Please post more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Primeface's Media tag to load swf. have a look at primefaces showcase

```
  <p:media value="http://www.youtube.com/v/KZnUr8lcqjo" width="420" height="315" player="flash"/>
```

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an application made in flex. Let's move some pages to primefaces so that future application works 100% with primefaces and jsf.

The start will be a menu, where the menu can reference both file.swf as file.xhtml. Or a file.swf import a file.xhtml. Any idea to do this?

I tried:

index.xhtml

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?> 
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- / / W3C / / DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict / / EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<Html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns: m = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns: w = "http://primefaces.org/ui" 
xmlns: ui = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

<h:head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title> JSF Application </ title> 
</ H: head> 

<h:body style="font-size: 12px"> 

<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="file.swf" /> 

</ H: body> 

</ Html>
```

It worked! But I want this:

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?> 
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- / / W3C / / DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict / / EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<Html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns: m = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns: w = "http://primefaces.org/ui" 
xmlns: ui = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
<ui:composition> 

<ui:define name="content"> 

<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="/file.swf" /> 

</ Ui: define> 

</ Ui: composition> 
</ Html>
```

I want to open with primefaces tags. Not worked!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question with this details. You can Edit your question. This place is for the answer.

Comment: How can I insert a file.xhtml in flex application?